# cygwin64 on WIndows 10: annoying pop-up "error the system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: cygwin

I use cygwin64 on a Windows 10 laptop. Almost every day, while typing, my oversized fingers and bad typing skills mash the keyboard and/or track-pad and I get this error pop-up:

```
Error: the system cannot find the file specified
C:\Users\Mark Logan\Downloads
```

This path exists and is readable

Comment: Where have you specified this `C:\Users\Mark Logan\Downloads` ? A cygwin program will use something like `/cygdrive/C/Users/Mark\ Logan/Downloads` including the \ escape for the `space` in the directory name.

Comment: That's a good question. I looked through the Cygwin options menu and I don't see any paths. I think it's something generated by some accidental key sequence, maybe copy/paste.

Comment: It seems more a Windows setting or program. I doubt it is coming from a cygwin setting

Answer (score 0):

When you type a file name in windows format, as in your example `C:\Users\Mark Logan\Downloads`, the backslash character '\' is processed as the character escape code. This changes the two characters '\U' to appear as a single 'U'. For a few characters, the two characters are replaced by a new character, e.g., '\b' inserts a BEL, '\r' inserts a CR, '\n' inserts a LF, '\t' inserts a TAB.

There are several ways to have a windows style filename properly read by a cygwin program, such as the bash shell. Note though that some programs will not interpret a windows style filename as a cygwin style filename.

- Wrap in single quotes: `'C:\Users\Mark Logan\Downloads'`
- Use escaped backslashes in double quotes: `"C:\\Users\\Mark Logan\\Downloads"`
- Use escaped backslashes and escape spaces: `C:\\Users\\Mark\ Logan\\Downloads`

Many cygwin programs, including most shells, use the readline library for input processing. This allows you to edit the input line before sending it to the program. You can use the left and right keys to move back and forth one character at a time, and the home and end keys to move to the start or end of the input line. You can add characters at the caret by typing them and remove characters before or after the caret by using the backspace or delete key. Pressing enter (or return) at any point in the line will send the edited line to the program.

In order to enter Windows style filenames so they are interpreted as the same file, the filename should be entered as a cygwin style filename, e.g., `C:\Users\Mark Logan\Downloads` as `/cygwin/Users/Mark\ Logan/Downloads` or `"/cygwin/Users/Mark Logan/Downloads"` (escape the space, or wrap in double or single quotes). You can use the cygpath program to perform this conversion (see cygpath --help).